# How to attach an running process to an existing screen in linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gnu-screen

I wish to debug a process which is already running using screen command.
Is there a way by which i can attach my running process with (some PID) to an existing screen (screen_name) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use screen to debug a process running as daemon. If you would want to debug a process, shut off the daemon mode and run it in screen. and use

```
screen -rd {screen_ID}
```